# SONOS Playback error "These Songs are not available for Streaming from APPNAME"

Tags: sonos, 7digital

I've been preparing POC to integrate our music service with SONOS, I've written simple service for testing purpose. I've implemented three essential methods to play url "getMetadata", "getMediaMetadata" and "getMediaURI".

First I've tried with media type "track" and returned song url(hard coded) from "getMediaURI" method which is .mp4 format, It worked fine as expected.

Later when I've tried with 7-digital url playback fails by saying "These Songs are not available for Streaming from "APPNAME". I've tried changing mime type values also nothing seems working. Type : audio/x-m4a

Note: Same 7 digital url is playing fine on browser.

Am I doing anything wrong here? Am I missing anything? Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation on Sonos' developer website, it doesn't seem like that `audio/x-m4a` is a supported MIME type. Do you know the audio format of 7-Digital's track for sure? If its mp4 or m4a, I would try setting the MIME type to one of these - `audio/mp4, audio/aac, 
application/x-mpegURL, application/vnd.apple.mpegURL, audio/x-mpegurl`

Also make sure that your track's sampling is supported as described in the table at the link below.

Link http://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/464

Comment: Thanks for ur reply, will check and get back.

Comment: audio/aac worked without tweaking any sampling rates.